# IE8 : submit event never catch by Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, extjs4.2

We have a bug with IE 8 and the submit event of a standard HTML form.
We use this code :

```
Ext.get('formulaire').on('submit', function() {
    console.log("submit event launched");
    // blabla
});
```

With Firefox, when I submit my "formulaire" form, the event is triggered and I can run some code.
With IE, the event is never triggered, or my callback function is never called.

Is there a way to have this working with IE 8 ? (it's the target of our application).

Answer (score 0):

Console will  be throwing error in IE 8,so comment

```
console.log("submit event launched");
```

and use the code

```
Ext.get('formulaire').on('submit', function() {


});
```